# Wi-Fi totally gone from Laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q with Windows 10x64 Home, today I noticed that my laptop does no more have option to connect to wifi, however before everything was fine, now i can only use ethernet, i tried all solutions i found - reseting with command line, reseting from settings and updated drivers, nothing helped me, and I also need to say that I cannot enter bios, because the boot screen does not tell me how to. please help!

**Edit** I have installed new wifi card and it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you opened your laptop and made sure that the antenna is properly connected to the wifi card?

Comment: i never opened my laptop, but the system should show wifi options even without antenna or not?

Comment: however i dont even know which one is antenna and which one is wifi-card

Comment: I  missed that in your question, but it could be that the wifi card has died or worked loose.

Comment: but... in device manager i can see it

Comment: To start BIOS Setup, press and hold the F2 key, and then turn on the
computer. Release the F2 key one second after the computer is power
on. Source http://support.toshiba.ca/support/isg/manuals/pscbxc/L850_L850D_L855_L855D_C850_C850D-C855_C855D-EnglishManual.pdf

Comment: even windows says that it works, but i still cant use it

Comment: Oh! Just was scrolling settings and found the details about wi-fi and it says that it is not running, or idk how to traslate it!!

Answer (score 4):

Laptops of this type have a hardware wifi on/off switch. It will be activated by holding down the function key (bottom left) and pressing one of the top line of keys on the keyboard. Look for one that may resemble an aerial or wifi related then whilst holding down function press that key. Your wifi should re-enable.

Comment: Well, mine doesnt have the wifi switch

Comment: @LilArtyXd https://smallbusiness.chron.com/locate-wireless-connection-switch-toshiba-laptop-52136.html

Comment: @LilArtyXd https://askubuntu.com/a/106791

Comment: Every Toshiba laptop has the wireless switch. Help us to help you and look for it.

Comment: Another possibility is airplane mode.

Answer (score 3):

On my Toshiba you have to press "FN" (Blue color) simultaneously with "F8" (that has a wireless network signal also in blue color).

Comment: It shows me the video/audio play/pause, next and previous buttons hud

Comment: On your keyboard it's only "F12".
P.S. - The previous option was "Network troubleshooter" .

Comment: seems like it does not have any effect

Comment: Are you in AirPlane Mode?

If not:
Go to:<br>
 Control Painel. (Search for it on Windows)<br>
 Network & Internet.<br>
 Network troubleshooter.<br>

If not solved press F12 key the repeat all.

Comment: I cant see Network Troubleshooter

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that you are not seeing the wifi list at all then this should help.

I have come across this issue since Windows 10 did some updates but I cannot tell which one (seems like one of the cumulative updates).

- Run Services as administrator.
- Double click on Wireless Connection Manager service.
- Goto Logon tab, change the "Log on as" to Local System account. Click on Apply.
- Goto General Tab, start the service and click OK.
- Goto WLAN AutoConfig and start the service as well.
  Now you should be able to see the Wifi list and connect to them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Little problem.. https://upload.hicoria.com/files/yc2tx8Ah.jpg I cant find it (I dont have updates downloaded)

Comment: I see the WLAN Autoconfig in the picture, you dont see the Wireless Connections Manager in the list? if you scroll up you should be able to see it.

Comment: No it isnt there