# WiFi and bluetooth functionality (possible controlling) gone from Windows 10 Home on laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-card

I own 7 years old Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q laptop and it is in very great condition, now let me tell you some story. I use the laptop for gaming and since for gaming the direct connection to internet is the best choice, ofc I was connected via cable, so I wasnt able to notice that Wi-Fi support is gone from my laptop, so I realized that after cleaning dust from inside, when I turned it up and making sure that everything works just fine, then I noticed that Wi-Fi doesnt work anymore. I tried all the methods recommended when the functionality is gone but nothing good, now Im about to buy a new Wireless card, but how can I make myself be totally sure that I wont just pay and then discover that there is other issue and wireless chip change does have not any effect. Im asking this, because Im young - 13 years old and Im not rich, I dont get a lot money as pocket so I need to invest carefully, since the chip costs 40€ and so I get only 5€/week. So please dont down vote for this :,(

**Edit** Also wanna tell you, that all the options and functionality of wifi is gone from windows (10 home activated x64), I can only see about wifi -  its properties in settings, device manager and somewhere in control panel

**EDIT** So I have replaced the wireless chip and nothing changed, so now the objective is to discover why windows 10 doesn't let me fully use bluetooth and wifi. Idk, I'll give as much info as i can;
- 30GB free on WD Blue SSD (500GB)
- 8GB ram (2x4GB)
- Wireless chip - Realtek / Broadcom
- GPU Amd Radeon (1GB) + HyperMemory
- CPU i3-2328M - 2x 2.2GHz, no turbo, 2nd gen

Comment: You could ask your friends and family if they have a dead or useless laptop you could salvage a WiFi chip from. The socket for them has been standard for quite some time.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the model of the laptop and googling how to run diagnostics on it. 

It could be simply that it needs a driver re-installed for it.

Comment: Does your WiFi router use 2.4 & 5 ghz ranges? Might need to enable TKIP/AES to get it working.

Comment: Well my laptop is Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q, and I was about firstly to check if wifi card will match my motherboard bcs i didint understand that but anyhow I didnt find anything even on its official site

Comment: @Smock aint really sure

Comment: @Smock I will edit my question, but let me let you know, the whole system does not have support for wifi, every settings in windows for wifi is gone, it shows only in device manager and somewhere control panel

Comment: @LilArtyXd Maybe there's a specific driver needed for that (rather than the generic one windows 10 will try to install) - have you checked the laptop manufacturers website for drivers? I found some on a [3rd party website](https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/toshiba/laptops-desktops/satellite-c850-19q/125523) but use at your own risk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi totally gone from Laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1494155/wi-fi-totally-gone-from-laptop)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to re-establish the wireless features of your wifi card by performing a few steps.

Open the device manager and select the wifi card. Right click on it and use the Uninstall option. DO NOT select the "delete files" option. It will be un-selected by default.

Complete the device uninstall and reboot the computer.

You should see an indication that new hardware has been found and that the system is installing the device drivers for it.

There's a strong possibility that this will restore functionality to your wireless. I have had to do this for clients' computers in the past, not only for wireless but sometimes for video drivers and sound drivers.