# Wifi gone from laptop - weird adventure continues

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, toshiba-laptop, broadcom

I have [posted](https://superuser.com/questions/1494813/wi-fi-chip-probally-died-but-did-it), [twice](https://superuser.com/questions/1494155/wi-fi-totally-gone-from-laptop), about WiFi failure on my Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q running Win10x64 Home.  I didn't get help that answered my problem, so bought a new chip from Broadcom.

Even after buying this new chip it doesn't work, I have also downloaded the drivers right, so can you tell me what else can cause this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi totally gone from Laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1494155/wi-fi-totally-gone-from-laptop)

Comment: I have added a solution that helps with WiFi list not showing up (if that is the same issue you are having) in the link posted by CaldeiraG above. If you want I can post it here as well. See if that helps.

Comment: This is the 3rd question you posted about this problem. Please don't do that.

Comment: @LilArtyXd Which Broadcom? Please click [edit] and put that model number in your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Check if the network adapter is disabled in the Device Manager. To open device manager search for "Device Manager" in the Windows search bar or hold Windows key + X and Device Manager will appear in the list that opens.

In the Device Manager window click Network adapters to open the list of adapters. Find your Wifi adapter on the list and if there's a small white circle with a black downwards pointing arrow beside an entry, this means a device is disabled.

To enable, right click the entry and click Enable device.

If your Wifi adapter isn't on the list, right click Network adapters and click Scan for hardware changes. Given you replaced the chip maybe forcing a search will make it appear.

You may also want to try updating or uninstalling then reinstalling the adapter using right click -> update or uninstall then reinstall.

As I can't comment it might be worth adding some extra detail to your question such as what the device is, operating system, some screen shots of your Device Manager etc.

Comment: Constructive critism on how to improve my answer instead of downvote please.